# Why is zener current preferred to be more than load current in a voltage regulator?

Tags: zener

In a simple Zener Voltage Regulator, such as this

[image: Zener Voltage Regulator]

**Why should current passing through the zener diode(zener current) be more than the current passing through the load(load current)?**

or

**No such conditions exist**

P.S. In my school notes, it was simply mentioned that this condition is required for "good load regulation"

Comment: @Qmechanic probably, yes

Comment: I agree, this is right up electronicsSE 's street.

Comment: Even the diagram is incorrect. The output is taken directly from the Zener, and not from a load resistor shunting the Zener. The load resistor is not part of the regulation mechanism but the device that is regulated.

Comment: "no such condition exist" should probably "no such requirement exits"?

Comment: @Wouter: "Requirement" is a good word for this, but in this case "condition" is used in the same way, as in *"Applying power is a necessary but not sufficient condition for this PIC to blink the LED."*

Answer (score 4):

No such condition exists.  The only restriction is that the current thru the zener diode be within its specified range so that it develops the desired voltage on the low end, and not dissipate too much power on the high end.  As long as this condition is met, the voltage will be regulated.

### Added:

I see from the comments that there is still some confusion.  Let's do a example that proves the stated restriction does not exist.  Suppose we have a zener that regulates to spec over the range of 1-20 mA.  Put less than 1 mA thru it, and its voltage will be too low.  Put more than 20 mA thru it and it blows up.

Now imagine that Rs is sized so that the maximum 20 mA flows thru the zener when there is no load.  This means that 20 mA always flows thru Rs as long as the voltage is being regulated.  The load can therefore draw anywhere from 0 to 19 mA with the voltage staying regulated.  The zener current will be 20 mA minus the load current.  You can see that there is quite a range where the load current can exceed the zener current, with 1 mA thru the zener and 19 mA thru the load being the extreme case.

Comment: The idea that the current through the Zener must be greater than through the load is probably a mistaken carry-over of principles of resistive voltage dividers, where the same conditions help to make the divider "stiff" with respect to load variations.

Comment: @olin Technically I think your answer proves this restriction does exist in some form.  If you put a load on that pulls more current than the zener it could shut off and stop conducting and load regulation would be lost.  Imagine just putting a 10 ohm load on, it would kill the regulation because the zener would no longer conduct.  Perhaps it is better stated in power as Pz>Pl?

Comment: What I was taught is that the zener will regulate voltage over a range of current from 0 to a maximum designed load current. Once the load current value exceeds the "no load" current through the zener, then the zener ceases to function and the voltage at the output will start to fall because the zener resistor and load resistor form a potential divider. For a simple regulator the current you choose to flow through the zener should be equal (at least) to the maximum (voltage regulated) current you require at the output.This will determine the power rating of the zener required for that circuit.

Comment: @JIMDearden Agree. I would say Pz>=Pl would be a safe rule to go by if when using Pz=Pl you are using the max Pl condition.

Comment: The label "Rs" is typically used only for modelling the characteristics of the voltage source and/or system impedance.  Is it not a fixed parameter in this example?

Answer (score 2):

No such requirement exists, however, if there's any possibility for the load to be disconnected, you should use a zener that is **capable** of handling the full load current.

If the load were to be disconnected (either due to a fault or due switching the load out as part of normal operation), then the zener will need to carry the full load current plus its normal operating current.

Answer (score 2):

What they meant to say:

- In order for a zener diode to regulate at the maximum load current which will be required, then when it is unloaded the zener current must be at least equal to this maximum load current and ideally will be somewhat greater.

Under these conditions Is will be constant for a given Vin

---

Longer:

It's likely that the "problem" here is that the point being made has suffered slightly in translation. As it stands it's not especially meaningful. By rewording slightly the probable original (and correct and useful) meaning can be arrived at.

As stated:

> In a simple Zener Voltage Regulator ...
>
> Why should current passing through the zener diode(zener current) be more than the current passing through the load(load current)?
>
> P.S. In my school notes, it was simply mentioned that this condition is required for "good load regulation"

What you are intended to understand:

Jin Dearden's commends got it right but may not be completely clear. (Or may be ;-) ).

Assume that:

- Vin1 = Vin2 for simplicity. Varying Vin alters results. Limiting case is when Vin is at the minimum end of its range.
- Ideal zener. No soft knee. Integrated shunt regulators such as eg TL431 come close to this .

In the unloaded case all input current flows in the zener so Izu = Is.
Vout = Vzener. This is the regulated voltage.
Is = Izener = Vrs / Rrs  = (Vin - Vz)/Rs
The voltage drop in Rs is just enough to drop the voltage from Vin to Vz.

Loaded case: If the current in Rs was increased by eg adding load current to the zener current then the output voltage would drop to below Vz. If this happened then the zenere would draw less current until Is was again the same as with no no load.  With an ideal zener the zener will sit on the infinitely sharp edge between conducting and not conductinhg. In the real world as the load takes current and Vout falls the zenere will move along its somewhat rounded VI curve until again balance is reached.

When the load current reaches Irs unloaded all the zener current has been taken by the load and the limit of regulation has been reached.

When the load takes more current than the zener was taking in the unloaded case then Irx x Rrs will be so large that Vout will fall to below the regulated vltage.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The Zener Diode is a voltage regulator here. It's purpose in the circuit is to effectively protect the load.  Protecting the load means you ensure that too much current does not flow through the load as excess current might damage it. Since it is approximated by (or it is) a resistor, one can limit the current flowing through it by restricting the voltage to a certain range. The Zener diode does this; it maintains the voltage difference between its terminals within a certain range. This will maintain the voltage across the load in the same range and I=V/R means the current is maintained at an appropriate level. Once the applied voltage is beyond that range, the Zener diode allows copious amounts of current through, but the voltage difference is always at the breakdown voltage; one of the extremes of the allowable range. In this way, it keeps the voltage drop across the load from being so large that the current flowing through it would be damaging. Any excess current flows through the diode. In a common voltage regulator application, the input voltage is usually outside the breakdown voltage of the diode. Thus, the current across the diode becomes large.  This is why it is better that the Zener current is larger than the load current, it means that the load voltage is maximized while at a safe current level.

Comment: Your explanation might be correct, but to me it is almost incomprehensible.

Comment: He is saying that the zener keeps the power at the load from increasing because it keeps the voltage fixed at Vz (by shunting current).  But it doesn't really answer the OP's question.